# Get array from external Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, external

I have an external json file `file.json` and I am trying to get an array stored inside of it so I can use it as a Javascript array. 
The JSON File:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "Steve",
            "Number": "120",
            "Number2": "78",
            "Number3": "75",
            "Number3": "85"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Bob",
            "Number": "130",
            "Number2": "98",
            "Number3": "85",
            "Number3": "85"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Number": "430",
            "Number2": "88",
            "Number3": "75",
            "Number3": "89"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is an array after the "data": and I would like to use that as an array.
This is what I have tried: (just to test)

```
$.getJSON( "file.json", function( json ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        var Test = json.data[i]; 
        console.log(Test.Name);
    }
});
alert(Test.Name);
```

Although it didn't return an array, the alert didn't work either. Is there a reason for this? And, if I could get variables or Objects outside the function, how can I create an array and get it outside? 
Thanks!

Comment: The `alert()` is outside of the callback, so it will probably error out, as `Test` is undefined. But everything inside looks fine. You've got nothing printed in your console? Any errors? Also check your "Network" tab, to see if you received the right data. On a side note, some browsers like Chrome will block Ajax requests if the files are stored locally. It needs to be served with the `http://` protocol, or other, but not `file:///`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention... yes, it is on a webserver. Console also mentions that Test is undefined after the function. (I want to be able to access Test outside of the function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Define it where you want it to be accessible
var people;

$.getJSON("file.json", function (json) {
    // Store the data in people to make it accessible globally
    people = json.data;
    people.forEach(function(person){ console.log(person.Name); });
    doSomethingElse();
});

// Would cause an error, you didn't receive the data yet
alert(people[0].Name); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

// Would work if it is called after receiving the data (inside the callback or later)
function doSomethingElse(){
    alert(people[0].Name); // 'Steve'
}
```

Comment: Console says that console.log(person.Name); is undefined 3 times, is there a reason to this?

Comment: @Amirkhanaursrk That's because I totally failed in using `for...in` the wrong way. A loop with an incrementing `i` works better in this situation (or other Array methods, like `.forEach()`). Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON()` is initiated at the same time as your `alert()`, but the callback function (`function( json )`) is not called until the data has been fetched and loaded.

So when you ask for `alert(Test.Name)` there is no `Test.Name` to alert! That hasn't been processed yet.

```
var Test = []
$.getJSON( "file.json", function( json ) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
      Test = json.data[i]; 
      console.log(Test.Name);
      alert(Test.Name);
   }
});
```

You won't be able to access Test outside the function as it is defined within. Defining it in the scope outside the function will allow it to be accessed, but until the JSON callback is complete it will be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the async operation of `$.getJSON`. Essentially what happens is the JS engine works through your program where it encounters the statement for `$.getJSON`, executes it (which then awaits a response in the event loop) and continues on to the next statement which is the `alert`. Since the event loop has not gone around to see if there has been a response yet the value for `Test.name` is `undefined` (which actually should have thrown an error unless you declared `Test` somewhere outside of the `$.getJSON` response handler).

For example:

```js
var foo;

// using setTimeout as a proxy async operation for $.getJSON
setTimeout(function() {
  foo = 'FOO';
  console.log('Inside the async operation', foo);
}, 0); // Approximate running in next loop of the event cycle

console.log('Outside the async operation', foo);
```

What do you think the output will be? Run it and check your console output or just look here:

```
> Outside the async operation undefined
> Inside the async operation FOO
```

So how do you get the value for the rest of your code without embedding it within the response function? The two main ways are either to use a callback function (similar to Node's preferred style) or to use promises.

If you didn't notice you are already using a callback function. That is what the function you are passing to `$.getJSON` is referred to as. So you could add more code to that function or factor it out to another function that is called from the existing response handler.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var foo = 'FOO';
  console.log('Inside the async operation', foo);

  myOtherCode(foo);
}, 0); // Approximate running in next loop of the event cycle

function myOtherCode(foo) {
  console.log('Outside the async operation', foo);
}
```

Or you could use promises. Since the native JS implementation of [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is relatively new a lot of libraries exist that allow you to use them on older browsers as well as including extra functionality.